Common Mode choke for radio interference

Wondering if anyone could guide me in a good direction.
This schematic go top redesigned for better protection, so top half become whats shown.
After that we started to notice that when XL4005 outputs 9V it makes any radio between 80-100Mhz get interference. Not always, but i managed to recreat the issue in my office.
Removing F1 reduces the interference alot but not good enough.
So i moddified one PCB by removing F1 and cutting the GND circuit on PCB that goes to T1 and T3. There i placed a CMC (ACM90V-701-2PL-TL) wich greatly reduced it to almost 0. But sometimes when i move the PCB it can still interfere the radio for like 1-3 seconds.
The PCB is designed to charge a tablet and send out an output V to other devices.
Issue only happens once tablet is in placed and being charged. The more A tablet draws the more interference on the radio.
I aslo tried placing the CMC first, so on input VCC1 and GND.
Is my placement of the CMC good, but i just need one with higher ohms?
Or is there something wrong with shematic design?
SW2 is a switch to change output from 5V to 9V charging.
When set to 9V interference is way higher then set to 5V. At 5V you cant notice it unless you really try. But at 5V tablet will not draw as much A either.
1250mA max @ 5V normaly around 800-1000mA
2500mA max @ 9V normaly around 1300-1800mA
Links to schematics and layout: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11MHvEdn4G8dRsCY3XwZUgrIGevsGNCT0&usp=drive_fs
Added info from todays testing:
Connectors are M12-8Pin that is for PWR and ETH. So for leads go to CN1 and 4 to CN2.
4 PWR leads are VCC1, GND GND and POUT.
On CN4 its a to lead wire just going to a on/off switch.
All cable lenghts are about 60mm long.
Switch and M12 connector is in the cradle, about 1cm away from PCB.
I just today made some more tests in my office. And placed instead ACM1513-551-2PL-HF on incomming VCC and GND to PCB. And i also removed F1. This had even better result, but with some "flicker" here and there. Talking less then 1sec, but i could se on radio that it displayed another freq brifely and a soft "pop" could be heard in the speaker.
Combining ACM1513-551-2PL-HF on incomming and ACM90V-701-2PL-TL on 5V/9V seems so far to remove all issues.
Also tid more test when charging is set to 5V with no filters and F1 present seems not to cause any interference.
Oh if it help input V is 10-30V, mostly its 24V.
So this layout and schematics somehow creates interference with FM radios around 80-100Mhz frequency in a few cases. And im hoping someone might have a suggestion for a CMC or other "filter" that might be able to solve this issue. Or is it the layout design thats causing the issue?
Layout composite:


The schematic is illegible I'm afraid -- can you scale it so text labels are readable? Thanks! || Particularly at these frequencies, layout is paramount. What does your PCB look like (Photos, layers)? What connectors/cables attach to it?

@TimWilliams If I open the schematic in a new browser tab and expand it to full size, it is readable.

@ChesterGillon Labels are 5-6 pixels tall -- they are mostly recognizable, yes, but not easily due to antialiasing/etc.  Many viewers will need to zoom in. And, seeing a poorly presented schematic, many will simply skip on past. :(

Links to schematics and layout: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11MHvEdn4G8dRsCY3XwZUgrIGevsGNCT0&usp=drive_fs

And updated new post with new findings.
And links to schematics and layout will get better layout drawings as soon as i get them from producer tomorrow
